# Uniquely complemented but not Boolean

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory, posets

What is an example of a lattice $(L,\leq)$ that is uniquely complemented, but not Boolean?

Comment: There exists a uniquely complemented lattice that is not distributive.  Why not see if you can find one?

Comment: Googling quickly gives http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186247 for instance

Comment: These comments in some sense answer the question, but there is no clue yet about how one goes about finding one, and Dilworth's paper is hard work. Is there an easy or natural example?  Are there finite examples? (added later: apparently the answer to the last is 'no') By the way, Huntington in 1904 conjectured that uniquely complemented lattices were Boolean/distributive, so the question is not trivial; indeed for decades it was a major outstanding problem in lattice theory. Birkhoff and von Neumann worked on it but only got partial results.

Comment: There is a whole book (V. N. Sali ̆ı, Lattices with unique complements, Translations of the Amer. Math. Soc., vol. 69, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R. I., 1988) which might be worth looking at. I can't get a good enough view from Google Books to say much more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are and this follows from Dilworth's construction of free uniquely complemented lattices. A simpler construction was later given by Chen and Grätzer [[On the construction of complemented lattices](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=232715), J. Algebra 11 (1969), 56–63]. There is a nice overview by George Grätzer in the AMS Notices in 2007: "[Two Problems That Shaped a Century of Lattice Theory](http://www.ams.org/notices/200706/)". Here is an excerpt that indicates that there were no other examples of non-distributive uniquely complemented lattices in 2007; I don't know if any new examples have been found in the last decade.

> All known examples of nondistributive uniquely
>   complemented lattices are freely generated,
>   one way or another. Is there a construction of
>   a nondistributive uniquely complemented lattice
>   that is different?
>
> In the same vein, is there a “natural” example of
>   a nondistributive uniquely complemented lattice
>   from geometry, topology, or whatever else?